# getting route custom data when route changes

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm writing an angular 12 component of a breadcrumb component, i know there are a lot out there, i'm trying to learn something here so go with it :)

so I'm trying to detect route change including the first route when the user opens the website, and I also need to add a custom data that I added to the route.

which means I have

```js
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, data: {breadcrumb: 'home'}}
```

as one of my routers, when user browses to the main page I will get an object with `{breadcrumb: 'home'}`

so in the constructor of my component I have the following:

```js
 constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    
             if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
              const data = this.route.root.snapshot.data;
              const url = event.url;
              console.info('data =>' + JSON.stringify(data));
        ...
```

the data object is always empty, I googled and there are  a lot of answers probably related to previous versions of angular that confused me and didn't really do anything.

for example I read somewhere that I need to check the event `RoutesRecognized` and there I can get the data, so I added

```js
     if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
         let route = event.state.root.firstChild!.data;
         console.info(route);
         console.info('RECOGNIZED');
       }
```

and this event is not fired at all, and I prefer to have all I need in one event.

I noticed that `NavigationStart` did not fire when i first load the page, only when i move to another route, so I used `NavigationEnd`, so I do get the url properly i just don't get the custom data.

so all I'm trying to do here is to get the url and custom data on url change. any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried `this.route.queryParams.subscribe(() => {})`? [Example](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MP.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.component.ts#L120)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok so the solution was simple..

the first page did not load on `ActivationStart` because I had `initialNavigation` set to 'enabled':

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    initialNavigation: 'enabled',
})],
```

i didn't really need that, when I removed that parameter `ActivationStart` would execute on the first page load.

and then I have :

```
 if (event instanceof ActivationStart) {

        const data = event.snapshot.data;
        const url = event.snapshot.url;
```

so i get the `data` object properly and the `url` comes as `UrlSegment` array.

and I can easily get child route data with:

```
    const childUrl = event.snapshot.firstChild?.url;
    const childData = event.snapshot.firstChild?.data;
```